# Why do the file paths of modules in the WOW64 PEB point to x64 versions of the module?

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm manually parsing the PEB's of a WOW64 process to get the modules loaded in it and was wondering why the file path (FullDllName) points to the x64 version of the module.

For instance, ntdll.dll's file path (taken from the WOW64 PEB) points to the DLL in the System folder which would be the x64 ntdll.dll, however, I would expect the file path to point to the x86 ntdll.dll in the SysWOW64 folder?

Why is this happening?

Comment: wow64 file system redirection. when it on, by default, the *system32* folder really redirected to *syswow64*. so from 32bit view - this dll paths really point to *syswow64*

Comment: They did a lot of work to make it look like you're running on a 32-bit OS.  Virtualizing the winapi and producing "looks like it" results.  But of course that buck stops somewhere, "manually parsing PEBs" is something they can't fake.  Use the normal winapi to do this, like CreateToolhelp32Snapshot() with the TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32 option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the x64 system, some special directories and special registry keys are divided into two separate parts. For file systems, the `%systemroot%\system32` directory is reserved for 64-bit files, and 32-bit files are redirected to the `%systemroot%\SysWOW64` directory. In other words, all 32-bit programs will normally only appear in the `%systemroot%\SysWOW64` directory. Any 32-bit program attempting to access the `%systemroot%\system32` directory will be redirected to the `%systemroot%\SysWOW64` directory. This is a default behavior unless the thread of the program explicitly specifies that the redirection mechanism needs to be turned off.

Sometimes you need to close redirection when you need to access the system 32 folder, so MSDN has provided a set of functions to control redirection:

[Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-wow64enablewow64fsredirection)

[Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wow64apiset/nf-wow64apiset-wow64disablewow64fsredirection)

[Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wow64apiset/nf-wow64apiset-wow64revertwow64fsredirection)

> MSDN provides DEMO, which you can refer to

Comment: Alternatively, use `SysNative` to access the 64-bit System32 directory from a WOW64 process.